# Displaying an attribute of a parent to child to parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

in the example below, what is the right way to display the item_category.name attribute within a box controller or view?

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item, :allow_destroy => true
end


class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
  belongs_to :item_category

end

class ItemCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  #contains 'name' attribute
end
```

I am anticipating there is some syntax like this which doesnt work:

```
<%= @box.item.item_category.name %>
```

this gives me the following error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

Thanks

EDIT:
sorry, the item class contains a belongs_to item_category (not company), I edited the sample.

Comment: Post the code in your controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your associations are set up properly, this is probably happening because your `Item` doesn't have an associated category, meaning its `item_category_id` field is `nil`.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the item class, it does indeed have a belongs_to :item_category. Updated original question. This example gets me this error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ok, updated the answer; make sure `item_category_id` actually has a valid value.

Comment: You are correct, I had modeled item_category as a string instead of a  item_category_id.